# jQuery nav .animate .hover --why wont this work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

I've got a side menu that I am trying to animate.
i want it to be visible on page load, then slide to the left margin.
On hover, I want each li to animate 150px to the right, and than back -150px on mouse leave.

I'm almost certain my code is correct, but ...nope.
Can you help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').animate( {left: "-110px"} );

//When mouse rolls over
  $('#nav li').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate( {left: "150px"}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'} );

  }, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate( {left: "-150px"}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'} );  

    });


  }); // end of document ready

</script>
```

Comment: Try changing `left: "150px"` to `left: "+=150px"`.

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: not sure how to do add my html. it tells me it's not formatted correctly...

Comment: left: "+=150px" didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `<li>`'s `position` to `relative` or alternatively use `margin-left`. Also, it's better to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` so that the events will be fired only when the mouse pointer is over the required element (see [mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) for further details). Try this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
$nav = $('#nav');
$nav.animate( {'left': "-110px"} );

//When mouse rolls over
$nav.find('li')
.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate( {'left': "150px"}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'} );
})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate( {'left': "-150px"}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'} );  
});
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/q9qEX/).

Comment: `.hover()` pretty much handles mouseenter and leave for you.

Comment: thanks! I tried it with mouseenter and mouseleave earlier and couldn't make it work. It was definitely the li's position that was tripping me up. Much appreciated!

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 yes you're right. It's that I'm not used to use the shortcut versions. Usually I prefer to use the `on()`/`off()` methods. @user2033669 you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/T5W2P/

You need to set the position to relative.

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav, #nav li {
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav').animate({
        left: "-20px"
    });
    //When mouse rolls over
    $('#nav li').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: "20px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 'slow'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 'slow'
        });
    });
});
```